# I would like to compare two arrays, and match highest occurrence from 1 to another?

Tags: java

I would like to compare two arrays containing numbers, numbers highest occurrence (Top 10) in **array2** to numbers in **array1**.  Example **array1** {**123**, 132, 231, 213, 312, 321,456, 765, 987} would mean that **123** in **array2** = 6 times.  This means **123** occurred 6 times in **array1**. The range for this is 000 - 999.  Each number in **array2** matches 6 numbers that maybe found in **array1**. Example **123** = 123, 132, 231, 213, 312, 321. Not counting numbers that repeat Example **111** or **177**. **Array2** has a fixed set of numbers while **array1** is updated.  What data type would I have to use? How would I count rearranged numbers?

This is what I got so far;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tuna {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array1[] = { 123, 132, 231, 213, 312, 321};
    int array2[] = { 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127};                       
    count(array1);
  }

    private static void count(int[] arr) {

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    int sum = 0, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[0] == arr[arr.length - 1]) {
        System.out.println(arr[0] + ": " + counter + " times");
        break;
    } else {
        if (i == (arr.length - 1)) {
            sum += arr[arr.length - 1];
            counter++;
            System.out.println((sum / counter) + " : " + counter
                    + " times");
            break;
        } else {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
                sum += arr[i];
                counter++;
            } else if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
                sum += arr[i];
                counter++;
                System.out.println((sum / counter) + " : " + counter
                        + " times");
                sum = 0;
                counter = 0;
               }
            }
         }
      }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: OK, you're almost there, as you've posted a requirement and code, but you still need to explain your code, tell us how it's not working, ask any specific questions... In other words, you've still got work to do to improve this question.

Comment: int array2[] = { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127};  your array also not valid

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha:  It *is* a valid declaration and instantiation of an array.

Comment: @Makoto but i got error 
integer number too long:018

Comment: number starting with 0 == octal

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha:  Those are octal numbers.  So yes, as stated, you would have an issue with those values in the array.  But the declaration itself is valid.  The array you pasted was actually correct, so I misread it.  This is what I get for not putting on my glasses before Stack Overflow.

Comment: 123 in array2 = 6 times?? what that means

Comment: Octal numbers don't invalidate the declaration but they are most likely not what was intended.  @user3765901 should use spaces to pad if they want to line up the commas between the arrays, not leading zeros.

Comment: None of the numbers repeat within their own arrays.  So highest (and lowest) occurrence within each array is exactly one for every number.  Could it be that you want to merge the arrays and then count the highest occurrence?  Because then 123 occurs twice while the other only occur once.

Comment: does you treat all permutation of a number.explain your question bit more.still not clear

Comment: **Array2** is a set of fixed numbers non-permutation numbers { 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239} Range 000 - 999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, than you want to count how often digit-wise permutations of numbers (000-999) in array2 occur in array1. You could do this by mapping all permutations of numbers in array2 to "permutation groups", allocate counters for each such group, and iterate through array1 finding groups and increasing counters. This code may do what you wanted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array1[] = { 123, 132, 231, 213, 312, 321 };
    int array2[] = {  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127 };
    count(array1, array2);
}

private static void count(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {

    // prepare a mapping of permutations of numbers in arr2 to arr2 indexes 
    int[] permutationGroupOfNumber = new int[1000];
    Arrays.fill(permutationGroupOfNumber, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        int number = Math.abs(arr2[i]) % 1000; // just to be safe
        int digit1 = number % 10;
        int digit2 = (number / 10) % 10;
        int digit3 = (number / 100) % 10;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit1 + digit2 * 10 + digit3 * 100] = i;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit1 + digit3 * 10 + digit2 * 100] = i;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit2 + digit1 * 10 + digit3 * 100] = i;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit2 + digit3 * 10 + digit1 * 100] = i;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit3 + digit1 * 10 + digit2 * 100] = i;
        permutationGroupOfNumber[digit3 + digit2 * 10 + digit1 * 100] = i;
    }

    // count the number of occurrences of permutations in arr1
    int[] occurrencesOfPermutationsInGroup = new int[arr2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        int g = permutationGroupOfNumber[arr1[i]];
        if (g >= 0)
            occurrencesOfPermutationsInGroup[g]++;
    }

    // output number of occurrences
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        int g = permutationGroupOfNumber[arr2[i]];
        if (occurrencesOfPermutationsInGroup[g] > 0)
            System.out.println(arr2[i] + ": " + occurrencesOfPermutationsInGroup[g] + " time(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I will add the fixed non-permutation numbers to array2 and update array1 see what happens.  I will drop all leading 0s and just assume if 12 comes up its 012.